# Highlight chart element when hovering over its corresponding legend Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to cause my Pie Chart in Charts.js (version 2.5) to highlight the appropriate slice when I hover over the corresponding legend item.

I have the following code which binds to the mouseover/mouseout events and calls my function, but I can not figure out how to highlight the appropriate slice.

```
// Function to bind mouseover/mouseout events
Chart.helpers.each(document.getElementById('legendID').firstChild.childNodes, function(legendNode, index) {
    Chart.helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseover', function() {
        highlightActiveSegment(myChart,index,true);
    });
    Chart.helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseleave', function() {
        highlightActiveSegment(myChart,index,false);
    });
});


// And the corresponding function highlightActiveSegment
function highlightActiveSegment(oChart,segmentIndex,highlight) {
    var activeSegment = oChart.data.datasets[0]._meta[1].controller._data[segmentIndex];
    window.chartAccidentsByRoadConditions.data.datasets[0]._meta[1].controller.setHoverStyle(activeSegment);
    /*
    if (highlight) {
        oChart.data.datasets[0].controller.setHoverStyle(segmentIndex);
    } else {
        oChart.data.datasets[0].controller.removeHoverStyle(segmentIndex);
    }
    */
}
```

Can someone show me PLEASE how to trigger the setHoverStyle and removeHoverStyle methods based on the legend item hovered over for ChartsJS 2.5

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qkfnfrx/) showing the problem.  As you will see in the example, there are errors in the console when hovering over a legend item due to the showHoverStyle and removeHoverStyle not being defined.  It would appear the ChartJS documentation that is currently online is not up-to-date.

**Full Example**

```js
var chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsClasses =  new Array();
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsClasses[0] = "Dry";
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsClasses[1] = "Not Available";
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsClasses[2] = "Wet";
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsClasses[3] = "Icy";
var chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsLabels =  new Array();
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsLabels[0] = "Dry";
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsLabels[1] = "Not Available";
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsLabels[2] = "Wet";
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsLabels[3] = "Icy";
var chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsData =  new Array();
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsData[0] = 31;
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsData[1] = 3;
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsData[2] = 3;
chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsData[3] = 1;

var dataAccidentsByRoadConditions = {
 labels: chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsLabels,
 datasets: [{
  data: chartAccidentsByRoadConditionsData,
  backgroundColor: [ "#82a8c3","#b24339","#053454","#77954b" ],
  hoverBackgroundColor: [ "#7597AF","#A03C33","#042E4B","#6B8643" ]
 }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
 var canvasAccidentsByRoadConditions = document.getElementById("chart-AccidentsByRoadConditions").getContext("2d");
 var chartAccidentsByRoadConditions = new Chart(canvasAccidentsByRoadConditions, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: dataAccidentsByRoadConditions,
  options: { 
   tooltips: {
    enabled: false
   },
   legend: {      
    display:false
   },
   legendCallback: function(chart) { 
    var text = [];
    text.push('<ul>');
    for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
     text.push('<li>');
     text.push('<div class="legendValue"><span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '">');
     text.push(chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] + '</span></div>');
     text.push('<div class="legendLabel">');
     if (chart.data.labels[i]) { text.push('<p class="label">' + chart.data.labels[i] + '</p>'); }
     if (chart.data.datasets[0].data[i]) { 
      text.push('<p class="percentage">' + chartValueToPercentage(chart.data.datasets[0].data[i],chartAccidentsByRoadConditions.getDatasetMeta(0).total) + '</p>'); 
     }
     text.push('</li>');
    }
    text.push('</ul>');
    return text.join("");
   }
  }
 });

 // Create our legend
 $('#legend-AccidentsByRoadConditions').prepend(chartAccidentsByRoadConditions.generateLegend());

 // Bind our "Break-Out" Chart function
 $('#chart-AccidentsByRoadConditions').on('mousemove mouseout',function(e){
  var activeSegment = chartAccidentsByRoadConditions.getElementAtEvent(e);
  pieChartHoverBreakout(this,activeSegment,e);
 });

 // Tie the legend to the chart tooltips    
 Chart.helpers.each(document.getElementById('legend-AccidentsByRoadConditions').firstChild.childNodes, function(legendNode, index) {
  Chart.helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseover', function() {
   highlightActiveSegment(chartAccidentsByRoadConditions,index,true);
  });
  Chart.helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseleave', function() {
   highlightActiveSegment(chartAccidentsByRoadConditions,index,false);
  });
 });     
});

function chartValueToPercentage(value,total) {
 return Math.floor(((value/total)*100)+0.5) + '%';
}

// Function breakout the active "legend item" PieCharts
currentBreakoutIndex = null;
function pieChartHoverBreakout(oChart, activeSegment, eventType) {  
 try { 
  // First, remove any existing classes with "breakout" from the legend
  var legend = ($(oChart).parent('.chartContainer').find('.legend')); 
  var segmentIndex = (activeSegment.length && (typeof activeSegment[0]._index != 'undefined' && activeSegment[0]._index !== null)) ? activeSegment[0]._index : -1;
  var breakout = (eventType.type === 'mousemove') ? true : false;
  if (currentBreakoutIndex != segmentIndex) {
   $.each(legend.find('li'), function(index,value) {
    $(this).removeClass('breakout');
   });
   // Second, if we have a valid segment index and breakout is true
   // we add the breakout class to the corresponding li in the legend
   if (breakout && segmentIndex >= 0) {
    currentBreakoutIndex = segmentIndex;
    var targetSegment = legend.find('li').get(segmentIndex);//
    $(targetSegment).addClass('breakout');   
   } else {
    currentBreakoutIndex = null;
   }
  }
 } catch(e) {
  // Nothing - just prevent errors in console
  console.log(e);
 }
}

function highlightActiveSegment(oChart,segmentIndex,highlight) {
  var activeSegment = oChart.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].controller._data[segmentIndex];

  if (highlight) {
    oChart.data.datasets[0].controller.setHoverStyle(activeSegment);
  } else {
    oChart.data.datasets[0].controller.removeHoverStyle(activeSegment);
  }
}
```

```css
#dashboardWrapper h2 { 
 display:block; 
 text-align:left; 
 margin-bottom:0px; 
 margin-left: 20px; 
 margin: 5px 0px 20px 0px; 
 line-height: 1.2;
}
#dashboardWrapper .chart {
  float:left;
 width:50%;
 vertical-align:middle;
 display:inline-block;
  width:50% !important;
  height:100% !important; 
}
#dashboardWrapper .legend {
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#dashboardWrapper .legendInfo {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888;
}
#dashboardWrapper .legendInfo span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;    
  margin-top: 5px; 
}
#dashboardWrapper .chart
{
 margin-bottom: 25px; 
}
#dashboardWrapper .chartContainer { padding: 20px 0px; }
#dashboardWrapper .chartContainer ul {
 background:none; 
}    
#dashboardWrapper .chartContainer li {
 background:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
 color: #666666;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 list-style-type: none;    
}
#dashboardWrapper .chartContainer li span {
  background-color: #791b15;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
}
#dashboardWrapper div.legendValue { float:left; width:20%; }
#dashboardWrapper div.legendLabel { float:left; width:80%; }
#dashboardWrapper p.label {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0;
 margin-right:10px;
 padding:0;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
#dashboardWrapper p.percentage {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 vertical-align:middle; 
}
#dashboardWrapper .dashboardElement
{
  display:inline-block; 
  min-height: 350px;
  float: left; 
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 2%;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#dashboardWrapper .chartContainer li 
{
    background: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
   padding:  0px 0px 5px 0px;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
   white-space: nowrap;    
   cursor:pointer;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    width: 94%;  
}

.chartContainer .legend ul li { 
  position:relative; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s; 
  left:0px;
}
.chartContainer .legend ul li.breakout { 
 left:-10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/download/v2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboardWrapper">
  <div class="dashboardElement right">
      <h2>Accidents by Road Conditions</h2>  
      <div class="chartContainer" style="position:relative;">
        <canvas id="chart-AccidentsByRoadConditions" class="chart" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
        <div id="legend-AccidentsByRoadConditions" class="legend"></div>            
      </div>                                                           
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `highlightActiveSegment` function and legend event handlers just has a few problems in it.  Here is a corrected version with explanation.

**Modified Legend Event Handlers**

You need to use `mousemove` instead of `mouseover` so that the section stays highlighted as the user moves the mouse around.

```
Chart.helpers.each(document.getElementById('legend-AccidentsByRoadConditions').firstChild.childNodes, function(legendNode, index) {
  Chart.helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mousemove', function() {
    highlightActiveSegment(chartAccidentsByRoadConditions, index, true);
  });
  Chart.helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseleave', function() {
    highlightActiveSegment(chartAccidentsByRoadConditions, index, false);
  });    
});
```

**Modified `highlightActiveSegment` Function**

Basically, the key is to make sure you get the actual segment of the graph represented by the moused over legend item, set the hover style accordingly and re-render the chart.

```
function highlightActiveSegment(oChart,segmentIndex,highlight) {
  var activeSegment = oChart.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[segmentIndex];
  oChart.updateHoverStyle([activeSegment], null, highlight);
  oChart.render();
}
```

Also, here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/peyROB) showing the working solution.

Comment: I've added a complete example as per your request.  Thank you for looking into this with me.  So far though, I still receive the setHoverStyle and removeHoverStyle is not defined error using your updated function.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for adding your complete example.  I got this working now!

Comment: I'll be checking this shortly, have not had a chance yet.  Will mark as correct as soon as I confirm.

Answer (score 0):

```
color: [
  {
    backgroundColor: ['#92d06f', '#73c8b8', '#3bb9ab'],
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
    hoverBackgroundColor: ['#92d06f', '#73c8b8', '#3bb9ab'],
    hoverBorderColor: ['#92d06f', '#73c8b8', '#3bb9ab'],
    hoverBorderWidth: 10,
    hoverRadius: 0
```

}
    ],

on mouse over highlights the active segment in angular 2(ng-2 charts) for doughnut charts